# How to add a default name space with dom4j?

Tags: java, dom4j

I would like to add a default name space to the root element of a XML document using dom4j, like in the following snippet. What is the correct way to do this with dom4j?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<animals xmlns="http://zoo.domain.org/schema/animals" >
    <animal id="1">
        <elephant>
            <name>Jumbo</name>
        </elephant>
    </animal>
</animals>
```

The dom4j API does provide the method `Element#addNamespace` but the javadoc tells that the prefix may not be blank.
The following code will result in the expected namespace for `animals` though:

```java
Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
Element animals = document.addElement("animals")
        .addNamespace("", "http://zoo.domain.org/schema/animals");
Element animal = animals.addElement("animal")
        .addAttribute("id", "1");
animal.addElement("elephant")
        .addElement("name")
        .addText("Jumbo");

// write document to file etc.
...
```

... but the child element `animal` gets an empty string as default namespace, which is not what I want:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animals xmlns="http://zoo.domain.org/schema/animals">
    <animal xmlns="" id="1">
        <elephant>
            <name>Jumbo</name>
        </elephant>
    </animal>
</animals>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Document#addElement` (but also `Element#addElement`) accepts a second parameter `namespaceURI`. That does the trick, adding the default namespace to the XML element.

The following code will result in the expected XML.

```java
Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
Element animals = document.addElement("animals", "http://zoo.domain.org/schema/animals");
Element animal = animals.addElement("animal")
        .addAttribute("id", "1");
animal.addElement("elephant")
        .addElement("name")
        .addText("Jumbo");

// write document to file etc.
...
```

Also worth mentioning is that in case you would like to create an Element on its own `DocumentFactory#createElement` has an overloaded version that accepts a `namespaceURI` as well. `DocumentHelper#createElement` does not have such an overloaded method.

Comment: Yep, that will do it. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the document (root) element.

```
Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
Element root = document.addElement( "animals" );
// TODO the rest of your code
```

Eventually, you'll pass your document to an XML writer to write (save) the document. Also, from Javadoc:

> Element **addNamespace**​(*java.lang.String prefix*, *java.lang.String uri*)
> Adds a namespace to this element for use by its child content
> Parameters:
> prefix - is the prefix to use, **which should not be null or blank**

One thing you could try is create an instance of `Namespace` passing a empty String to the constructor and use the `Element.add()` method instead. The Javadoc of `Namespace` doesn't indicate that the prefix can't be blank.

Comment: You're right about my example code snippet. The snippet doesn't show the creation of the document. The intention was to show just a snippet that would contribute to the expected XML. I had to revisit the question to be more specific and clear about that.

Comment: @BartWeber The rest of my post is right on topic though; you cannot add a namespace without a valid prefix. But, try my suggestion of creating the `Namespace` object and passing it an empty prefix. That might work. I am not sure though.

Comment: True! Thank you for answering this question! Unfortunately it has the same unwanted result as mentioned: element `animal` gets an empty string as default namespace.

Comment: @BartWeber are you stuck with dom4j? If not, why not try JAXB?

Comment: As far as I know can JAXB only map Java classes to XML representations (and visa versa). I need to build XML files dynamically.

Comment: @BartWeber in that case, JAXB is not the answer.